# Функция окрашивания ячеек с "плавающим" количеством переменных

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Хочу сделать через функцию заливку произвольным цветом произвольное количество ячеек и/или диапазонов. В функцию вводится цвет и сами диапазоны. Со цветом проблем нет, но как сделать "плавающие" количество диапазонов(Как например у базовых функций `IFS` и `SWITCH`)? Сам информацию не нашел, а вариант с кучей переменных не очень подходит и просто звучит.

```js
// Текущая функция выглядит сейчас так: 

function zero(color, range1, range2, range3) {
 var sheet1 = sa.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("List");
 var range0 = sheet1.getRangeList([`${range1}`, `${range2}`, `${range3}`]);
 range0.setBackground(`${color}`);}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Пользовательская функция не имеет прав на изменение свойств Таблицы. Или это не пользовательская функция?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это довольно странный вопрос, т.к. код показывает не то, что задается.

Предположим, что добывать цвета мы будем итератором

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {any[]} arr
 * @param {callback} extractor
 * @returns {@yields}
 */
const pickFromIterator_ = (arr, extractor) =>
  (function* () {
    let index = 0;
    while (true) {
      index = index >= arr.length ? 0 : index;
      yield extractor ? extractor(arr, index) : arr[index++];
    }
  })();
```

Обратите внимание, что мы можем переопределить порядок вывода значений с помощью `extractor`. Это понадобится для рандомного выбора.

Покраску всего сведем к перебору всех диапазонов

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {string[]} colors
 * @param {string[]} rangeNames
 * @param {@yields} picker
 * @param {globalThis.SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet
 */
function colorRanges_(
  colors,
  rangeNames,
  picker = pickFromIterator_(colors),
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
) {
  rangeNames.forEach((rangeName) =>
    sheet.getRange(rangeName).setBackground(picker.next().value)
  );
}
```

Чтобы запустить пример нужно реализовать вызов функции `colorRanges_`

```js
/**
 * Runs the sample
 */
function run() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().clearFormats();

  const colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];

  const picker = pickFromIterator_(colors);
  colorRanges_(colors, ['A:A', 'C:C', 'D:D', 'E:E'], picker);

  const picker2 = pickFromIterator_(
    colors,
    (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  );
  colorRanges_(colors, ['F:F', 'G:G', 'I:I'], picker2);

  // Continue with picker
  colorRanges_(colors, ['J:J', 'K:K', 'L:L', 'M:M'], picker);

  // Default
  colorRanges_(colors, ['N:N', 'O:O']);
}
```

Обратите внимание

- следующие две колонки будут покрашены рандомно на основании значений `randomExtractor`
- количество диапазонов не зависит от количества цветов задавать можно любое количество большее чем ничего.
- После комментария `// Continue with picker` програма продолжает использовать текущий итератор, а не начинает новый как после `// Default`.
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица с кодом https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VwM_FpwspSedrcacAdv1P73IwOHC45X15SBNftkt2TY/edit?usp=sharing